# pass object from directive to controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im tying to pass object from directive to controller. function is called in controller form directive but parameter i pass to controller function is undefined.
here is my code.

```
//controller function 
$scope.edit_task = function(task) {

        console.log(task);// this in undefined
};

// directive
myApp.directive('task', function() { 
    return {
        restrict : "EA",
        templateUrl : "/views/directives/task.html",
        scope: {
            taskList: '=',
            task: '=',
            editTask: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           element.on("change", function(){
                console.log(scope.task) // this ok. 
                scope.editTask( scope.task );
           });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad i forget to pass parameter in view.
i changed from this

```
edit-task="edit_task()"
```

to this in my view

```
edit-task="edit_task(task)"
```